# Spring Security Regex Exclude by path

Tags: regex, spring, security

I am using the following to allow access in Sprint Security to all URLs which match 'create.action'

```
<intercept-url pattern="^(.*?)(\bcreate.action\b)(.*)$" access="hasAnyRole('1','2')"/>
```

However i would like to grant access to /path1/path2/create.action  to roles '3' and '4' i.e /path1/path2/create.action is an exception to the above rule.

I tried `^(.*?)(\b/path1/path2/create.action\b)(.*)$` but it doesn't work. I also tried the absolute path and that doesn't work too. Please help.

Comment: did you try to escape slashes / : `^(.*?)(\b\/path1\/path2\/create\.action\b)(.*)$`

Comment: Thanks . That's what i was missing .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape slashes `\` and dots `.` and remove `\b`, it matches a word boundary where a word character is [a-zA-Z0-9_]

```
^(.*?)(\/path1\/path2\/create\.action)(.*)$
```